# Missing Xml Tag in Golang

Tags: go

I am new to golang I am trying to make a xml in which i am using nested tags

For that my code is

```
type MyXml struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"myXml"`
    Id      int      `xml:"id,attr"`
    NewXml
}
type NewXml struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"newXml"`
    OneMoreXml
}

type OneMoreXml struct {
    Msg interface{} `xml:"oneMore"`
}

type Child struct {
    Param1 string `xml:"Param1"`
}

func main() {

    baseXml := &Child{Param1: "Param1"}
    retXml := GetXml(baseXml)
    fmt.Println("my xml is", retXml)

}
func MarshallXml(reqString interface{}) (newXml string) {
    xmlBody, err := xml.Marshal(reqString)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("error: %v\n", err)
    }
    newXml = string(xmlBody)
    //fmt.Println(newXml)
    return
}
func GetXml(baseXml interface{}) (finalXml string) {

    startXml := new(MyXml)
    startXml.Id = 1
    startXml.Msg = baseXml
    finalXml = MarshallXml(startXml)
    return

}
```

but in my output xml Tag newXml is missing. I have tried it in various ways but some tag is always missing. I guess i am not understanding struct tag properly. So What i am doing wrong in above code and which basic concept of golang struct i am missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a look at the xml package doc and they say that "an anonymous struct field is handled as if the fields of its value were part of the outer struct". In your case, all fields thus get serialized as if they were part of MyXml.

NewXml does not have any field (you just give it a name but there is nothing else) so nothing gets serialized for it.
If you add a new field to it, you can see that it is serialized.

```
type NewXml struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"newXml"`
    Test    int
    OneMoreXml
}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/vibSeQHTCr

Comment: in your playground example i want onemore tag as a child of Test tag instead of both tags being child of myxml
i want the xml as below:
<myXml id="1"><Test><oneMore><Param1>Param1</Param1></oneMore></Test></myXml>

Comment: Then I think you need to have a named instance of OneMoreXml and not just an anonymous struct. As shown here: http://play.golang.org/p/ssHw0UVpU3

Comment: its work thanks but can u explain me what difference does it make? or u can share some link of the same.

Comment: According to the doc at http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/, "an anonymous struct field is handled as if the fields of its value were part of the outer struct."
I think this sentence means that NewXml was not "seen" as a field of MyXml: instead, all NexXml's fields were processed as if they had been part of MyXml. In the initial case, this led down to the "Msg" field of OneMoreXml.